# Почему Cookie не доступна при ее задании?

Tags: веб-программирование, cookie, php, javascript

Всем привет. Такие дела задаю на сервере:

```
$_COOKIES['test'] = 1;
```

а потом обращаюсь к ней на js:

```
 var first = $.cookie('test');
```

и получаем undefined.

Так только при первом разе (когда кука задается первый раз), потом все норм. Почему так?

Answer (score 2):

[[@Артур Пантелеев](/users/13192/%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2)](/users/13192/%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2), куки хранятся на клиенте. Для того, чтобы куки записались, они должны вернуться в Responce Headers (заголовки ответа) вместе с остальными данными (например, HTML). Только тогда они будут реально созданы.

Например, следующий код будет нерабочий при первом запуске:

```
setcookie('asd', 5, 0, '/'); //функция для задания кук
echo $_COOKIE['asd'];
```

Но при второй запуске выведет 5. Как это работает:

До вывода любых данных мы формируем заголовки ответа, используя функцию setcookie, указываем, что нужно создать переменную, хранящуюся на клиенте. Далее идет остальной код, например, вывод HTML. В браузере в заголовках ответа сервера будет вот такая строка `Set-Cookie:asd=5; path=/`, когда она пришла - браузер запоминает переменную. При втором запросе на сервер, браузер отправляет данные о хранимых куках в Request Headers (заголовки запроса): `asd=5;` - т.е. он отправляет эти данные на сервер. Только тогда сервер может обработать данную переменную в массиве `$_COOKIE`.

Comment: спасибо за подробное описание, но разве javascript код отрабатывает не после получения $_COOKIE?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы не правильно работаете с куками.

[`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php)