# Правильный вывод cookies в php

Tags: php, cookie

Написал такой код:

```
    $trus = $_POST['trus'];
    $ttat = $_POST['ttat'];

    if($ttat == false){
        $t = 0;
        setcookie("tr","$t", time()+3600, '/');
    } elseif($trus == false) {
        $t = 0;
        setcookie("tr","$t", time()+3600, '/');
    }

$th = $_COOKIE["tr"];
```

Проблема в том, что сначала открывается сайт без этих данных куки. Только после обновлении страницы с куками.
Как делать так, чтобы сразу открылся с куками, без всяких обновлений страниц?

Comment: Вы вот так `if($ttat == false)` проверяете наличие в POST запросе переменной `ttat`?

Comment: Был уже подобный вопрос, с ответом. Можете почитать [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/395378/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-cookie-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8/395417#395417)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `setcookie()` предварительно собирает из своих аргументов строку для HTTP-заголовка `Set-Cookie` в соответствии с [RFC-6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.1) и в конце делает то же самое, что и конструкция `header('Set-Cookie', ...)`. Таким образом куки будут переданы браузеру вместе с ответом сервера.

Массив `$_COOKIE` заполняется на основе данных HTTP-заголовка `Cookie`, полученного из запроса браузера.

Именно поэтому данных о только-что установленных куках нету в массиве `$_COOKIE`. Причем идея "чтобы сразу открылся с куками" врядли является удачным решением, поскольку нарушает логику работы кук на стороне сервера. Это может принести немалую головную боль при поддержке продукта с таким "решением".

Если вам нужны данные, которые вы только что записали в куки - берите их из той переменной, которую вы использовали в функции `setcookie()`. Например можно было бы реализовать это так:

```
$defaultValue = 0;

if (!$ttat) {
    setcookie("tr", $defaultValue, time()+3600, '/');
} elseif (!$trus) {
    setcookie("tr", $defaultValue, time()+3600, '/');
}

$th = isset($_COOKIE["tr"]) ? $_COOKIE["tr"] : $defaultValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Куки не успевают записаться сразу, и станица загружается без них. Поэтому они появляются только если обновить страницу.
Вернее они записываются во время загрузки страницы. 
Чтобы увидеть их в переменной `$_COOKIE`, можно принудительно их туда запихнуть.
Например так:

```
setcookie("tr", $t, time()+3600, '/');
$_COOKIE['tr'] = $t;
```